# SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information if accessing red5 homepage

Tags: java, windows, windows-server-2003, red5, socketexception

I have just installed red5 on Windows server and now trying to access it's homepage at 5080.

I see in output at the moment of accessing

```
[ERROR] [http-m.y.i.p-5080-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setIntOption(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setTrafficClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties.setProperties(SocketProperties.java:184) ~[tomcat-coyote-6.0.36.jar:6.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:1089) ~[tomcat-coyote-6.0.36.jar:6.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1314) ~[tomcat-coyote-6.0.36.jar:6.0.36]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
[ERROR] [http-m.y.i.p-5080-Acceptor-0] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint - java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument: no further information
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setIntOption(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setTrafficClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties.setProperties(SocketProperties.java:184) ~[tomcat-coyote-6.0.36.jar:6.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:1089) ~[tomcat-coyote-6.0.36.jar:6.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$Acceptor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1314) ~[tomcat-coyote-6.0.36.jar:6.0.36]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_25]
```

No errors while strtup.

I found in the Internet, that the solution is to set `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters\DisableUserTOSSetting=0` and reboot a machine.

But I can't reboot a machine since it is in use.

What is the nature of this error?

Is there any way to install `red5` on Windows Server without rebooting it?

May be downgrade Java or red5?

Comment: Other comments on the net says that the latest versions of Tomcat 7 fix the problem. You'll therefore have to "only" upgrade Tomcat, no need to shut down the machine.

Comment: I don't use Tomcat :) It's red5 -- a separate server :)

Comment: Well, if you look at your stack trace, you can see that red5 uses tomcat at the core ;)

Comment: Yes because it is a fork. If you suggest to upgrade part of `red5` with new Tomcat parts then pls explain in more detail.

Comment: Tomcat is one of the JEE containers available for handling web requests in red5; it is not the only option.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that a socket option is being set, but I'm not sure where that would be happening or why. We don't set any for tomcat that I'm aware of. You could try switching the connectors in the jee-container.xml

```
    Blocking I/O:
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" />
    Non-blocking I/O:
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" />
```